# Can't fix this script

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have an issue with my script. I think it something to do with the "end" but I do not really know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: This code is correct.

Comment: I wanted to make it so when I join the game it only shows it to my character

Answer (score 1):

All you did wrong is get the code in the wrong order! Oh and you you need to add a bracket on to the end) Just do it like this:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Name == 'MateoGaming_YT' then
        player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local trail = game.ServerStorage.Trail:Clone()
        trail.Parent = char.Head
        --And all the rest of the trail bit
        end)
    end)
end)
```

If you need anymore help, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of Vigus Widdicombe-Gasson's answer. It looks like you corrected your script before taking the screenshot of your code.

The error that shows up in red in the `Output` window tells you how to figure out what's wrong here.

```
 ServerScriptService.Script:14: ')' Expected (to close '(' at line 3) near <eof>
```

This error says that in `ServerScriptService`, there is a `Script` that threw an error on line 14.

This error is `')' Expected near <eof>`. This means that a closing parenthesis was expected somewhere, but the script made it to the end of the file before it found it. Additionally, it tells us that the opening to this parenthesis was located on line 3.

So all you need to do to fix this is add a `)` in the right place. Your code indenting makes it hard to see where the error is, but it should go after one of your end) statements.

I'll retype your code here for clarity :

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)    
    if player.name == 'MateoGaming_YT' then
        player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)    -- << this line needed a close parenthesis

            -- be careful how you indent here, try to keep everything in the correct tab
            local attachment0 = Instance.new("Attachement", char.Head)
            local attachment1 = Instance.new("Attachement", char.HumanoidRootPart)
            local trail = game.ServerStorage.Trail:Clone()
            trail.Parent = char.Head
            trail.Attachment0 = attachment0
            trail.Attachment1 = attachment1

        end) -- end player.CharacterAdded
     end -- end if
end) -- end game.Players.PlayerAdded
```